# update Map key's value java

Tags: java, treemap

Ok I have this code:

```
TreeMap<DateTime, Integer> tree2 = getDatesTreeMap();
DateTime startx = new DateTime(startDate.getTime());
DateTime endx = new DateTime(endDate.getTime());
boolean possible = false;
int testValue = 0;
//produces submap
Map<DateTime, Integer> nav = tree2.subMap(startx, endx);

for (Integer capacity : tree2.subMap(startx, endx).values()) {
    //Provides an insight into capacity accomodation possibility
    //testValue++;
    terminals = 20;
    if(capacity >= terminals)
        possible = true;
    else if(capacity < terminals)
        possible = false;

}

if(possible == true)
{
    for (Integer capacity : tree2.subMap(startx, endx).values()) {
    {
        capacity -= terminals;
        //not sure what to do
    }
}
}else{

}

return possible;
```

It checks for range of date in submap. then checks if values of those dates (which are keys btw) can accomodate terminals (that is reservation number), then if yes it would subtract that from capacity currently in map. I am unsure how to update the capacity in the map for all dates between startx and endx with value

```
capacity -= terminals;
```

Thanks,
:)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to reinsert the key / value into the map with the updated value.

```
tree2.put(key, tree2.get(key) - terminals);
```

Comment: how can I get access to the key in this instance? Because all my keys are DateTime type...Any hints?

Comment: Don't loop over the values, loop over the keys of the sub-map instead. (Going from key to value is easy.)

Comment: @sys_debug what about `tree2.subMap(startx, endx).keySet()`?

Comment: So i change Integer Capacity to DateTime datex then change .values() to entrySet()? but that gives an error :(

Comment: Not `entrySet`, use `keySet`. Then pick up the capacity using `yourSet.get(datex)`.

Comment: @Thomas ok did that, but what am asking is how to access the key's and their values in the body? because I still need to do exactly the same comparison that is capacity >= or  <=  terminals

Comment: @sys_debug If you have the key from `keySet()` you access the value like @aioobe showed you. Note that `keySet()` will return `DateTime` objects.

Comment: @Thomas I am really confused as to what type am declaring in the for each...right now if I do this:

for (DateTime x : tree2.subMap(startx, endx).keySet())

then what am I going to invoke .get() on? am sorry but am really really new to this all

Comment: @sys_debug in your loop you employ @aioobe's answer (just replace `key` with `x`).

Comment: aha now it is clear :D Thanks @Thomas really really appreciate it